# Spring boot - UserDetailsService returned null, which is an interface contract violation in multipart websecurity config

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to set multi jwt securityconfig
and i make a general class
it's work with 2 config
but when i add third part (order 3) it's not working
and give me 'UserDetailsService returned null, which is an interface contract violation'
this is my class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
    @Autowired
    private MarketerService marketerService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(marketerService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new PasswordEncoder() {
            @Override
            public String encode(CharSequence charSequence) {
                return charSequence.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matches(CharSequence charSequence, String s) {
                return charSequence.toString().equals(s);
            }
        };
    }


    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(
                "/api/marketer/auth/**",
                "/api/business/auth/**",
                "/api/customer/auth/**",
                "/api/operator/auth/**").permitAll().
                        anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                        exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class SecondWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
    @Autowired
    private BusinessService businessService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(businessService).passwordEncoder(SecondPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder SecondPasswordEncoder() {
        return new PasswordEncoder() {
            @Override
            public String encode(CharSequence charSequence) {
                return charSequence.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matches(CharSequence charSequence, String s) {
                return charSequence.toString().equals(s);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(
                "/api/marketer/auth/**",
                "/api/business/auth/**",
                "/api/customer/auth/**",
                "/api/operator/auth/**").permitAll().
                        anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                        exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(3)
public static class ThirdWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;
    @Autowired
    private OperatorService operatorService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(operatorService).passwordEncoder(ThirdPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder ThirdPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(
                "/api/marketer/auth/**", "/api/business/auth/**", "/api/customer/auth/**",
                "/api/operator/auth/**").permitAll().
                        anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                        exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

}

if i remove my order 3 it's fine but i want to have 4 config

Comment: how about OperatorService class?

Comment: if the method loadUserByUsername() return null, you will receive message like above.